# Regex for wrapping digits with curly braces?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I am trying to using Python's `re.sub()` to match a string with an `e` character and insert curly braces immediately after the `e` character and after the lastdigit. For example:

```
12.34e56 to 12.34e{56}
1e10 to 1e{10}
```

I can't seem to find the correct regex to insert the desired curly braces. For example, I can properly insert the left brace like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = '12.34e10'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(e)')
>>> sub = z = re.sub(pattern, "\1e{", x)
>>> print(sub)
    12.34e{10 # this is the correct placement for the left brace
```

My problem arises when using two back references.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = '12.34e10'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(e).+($)')
>>> sub = z = re.sub(pattern, "\1e{\2}", x)
>>> print(sub)
    12.34e{} # this is not what I want, digits 10 have been removed
```

Can anyone point out my problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'e(\d+)', r'e{\1}', '12.34e56')
```

returns `'12.34e{56}'`

or, the same result but different logic (don't replace `e` with `e`):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=e)(\d+)', r'{\1}', '12.34e56')
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help. The look behind trick is really cool.

Comment: In the second solution, why is `r'{\1}'` used instead of `r'{\2}'` for the substitution? I experimented with using `r'{\2}`, but this resulted in an error. Are look behinds not supported in back references?

Comment: @dr.bunsen Correct, the look-behind is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Your brace placement is incorrect.

Here's a solution ensuring the that there's a number with optional decimal place before the `e`:

```
import re
samples = ['12.34e56','1e10']
for s in samples:
  print re.sub(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)e([0-9]+)',"\g<1>e{\g<2>}",s)
```

Yields:

```
12.34e{56}
1e{10}
```

Comment: I think just expanding eumiro's second one to `r'(?<=\de)(\d+)'` is probably adequate?

Comment: @agf: Agreed, that would pobably be adequate.